# How to access data from HTML form in views.py?

Tags: python-2.7, django-forms, forms

when i create my form entirely in HTML, how to access the form data in views.py? 
I want to create a form entirely in HTML without using django form class. When i have done, how to access the form field data in the views.py?. I want to use the data at backend. Please help me

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>
 HTML forms
 </title>
</head>
<body>

<p> This is a simple form</p>
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
 <fieldset>
 <legend> Personal Information</legend>
 <label for="name">contact_name:<br></label>
 <input type="text" name="contat_name" id="name"><br> 
 <label for="email">contact_email:<br></label>
 <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required placeholder="example@example.com"><br>
 <label for="content">content:<br></label>
 <textarea name="content" rows="10" cols="30">
 </textarea>
 <br>
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </fieldset>
 </body>
 </html>
```

this is my HTML form i want to access the contact_name and contact_email in views.py. how to access the data?

```
def htmlform(request):
if request.method=="POST":
    print request.POST.get("contact_name")      
return render(request,"htmlform.html")
```

when i used request.POST.get("contact_name") it returns nothing.

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible example

Comment: please see the edited field

Comment: sorry everyone. its because of spelling mistake. i have typed contat_name instead for contact_name in HTML file

Answer (score 1):

In the Html you've give name as "**contat_form**" and in the views.py you're trying to access the name as "**contact_form**"

Answer (score 0):

This is because in your views.py you are trying to access `contat_form` whereas the actual field name in the html form is contact_form. Otherwise your method is correct.